# Is there a concise form of Which or similar conditional?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Suppose that I want to write a function `fun` that takes an `Integer` `num` as input, and returns `Red` if `num == 1`, `Orange` if `num == 2`, and `Yellow` if `num == 3`.  One way, I think, to do this is to use `Which`:

```
fun[num_Integer] := Which[num == 1, Red, num == 2, Orange, num == 3, Yellow]
```

Is there a more concise way to write `fun`?  In other words, is there any built-in function (analogous to `Which`) that I can use that would allow me to avoid typing "`num`" all the time instead of always having to specify it to `Which`.  Writing `fun` as a series of nested `If` statements would be even lengthier.

Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I usually use `Switch` as per @jVincent below

Comment: Every single one of the methods I thought of are already in the four answers below.  That doesn't happen often.  Nice coverage guys!

Comment: We probably need to add `PiecewiseColor`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not really a concise syntax, but you can also do this using Switch, which removes the need for writting the checking, and also allows patterns:

```
fun[num_Integer] :=
  Switch[num,
  1, "Red",
  2, "Orange",
  3, "Yellow",
  _?PrimeQ, "Purple",
  _, "LightGray"]
```

I used strings just to make the output nicer to verify the behavior. Naturally you would switch these to the actual colors.

```
Style[#, fun@#] & /@ Range@20
```

[image: Numbers colored using the function]

Answer (score 26):

For example you may do something like

```
f[i_] := {Red,Orange,Yellow}[[i]]
```

**Edit**

You can easily add some robustness:

```
f[l_List, i_Integer ] := l[[i]] /; 1 <= i <= Length@l;

ll = {Red, Orange, Blue};
f[ll, 3]
(* RGBColor[0, 0, 1] *)
```

Comment: If you want periodicity: `l[[Mod[i, Length[l], 1]]]`.

Answer (score 18):

You could use [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to write your function this way:

```
fun[num_Integer] := num /. {1 -> Red, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Yellow}
```

This also allows pattern matching, and works better than switch in case you want to name parts of your pattern:

```
findpeople[dbconn_, name_] := DBSelect[dbconn, "People", name] /. {
   $Failed :> (Message[findpeople::conn]; $Failed),
   {} :> (Message[findpeople::empty]; $Failed),
       results_List :> results,
       other_ :> (Message[findpeople::err, other]; $Failed)
}
```

Comment: Big +1. Not enough love for this answer, folks! The possibility to transparently incorporate error-handling is very valuable. I use similar constructs a lot too.

Comment: +1, you might want to use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` for slightly more robustness when replacing unexpected expressions...

Answer (score 15):

One simple solution is:

```
fun[1] = Red;
fun[2] = Orange;
fun[3] = Yellow;
```

A more complex solution that accepts arbitrary equivalence lists at run time:

```
fun[{ins_, outs_}] :=  Function[x, Piecewise[MapThread[{#2, x == #1} &, {ins, outs}], x]];

f = fun[{{1, 2, 3}, {Red, Orange, Yellow}}];

f[2]
```

> RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]

Comment: I think it is a little more efficient to use `fun[1]=Red`,etc. Using `:=` means that the token `Red` will evaluated on every call to `fun`, rather than once.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: If you do `f[_]=x; x=2;`, then `f[9]` will have to reevaluate `x` regardless of having used an immediate assignment. If MMA is smart enough to not check when the assignment is to an atom, them it probably is also smart enough with a delayed assignment. But I'm not certain

Comment: However, what does make a difference is to set `fun` some holding attribute.

Comment: Ok, Forget what I said, I forgot that `Red` and friends actually evaluate to `RGBColor`

Comment: The first method, which creates DownValues rules, is usually the fastest and canonical approach.  I recommend this answer for the Accept.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I still think it should be edited by image doctor to use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I made the edit; there was simply no reason not to.

Comment: One sleeps, magic happens.